# dataTables Change Data for ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax, datatables

I'm using the following function to load a DataTables table with data from the server. I would like to reload the table with different parameters on a click event only i cant work out how to do this. If i call reload it just reloads with the original parameters if i reinitialise the whole table it throws an error as the table already exists.

I have been looking into fnServerParams but cant work out if it would help or not.

If anyone can point me in the correct direction that would be great.

```
function LoadRiskProfileModalTable(userId, teamId, riskProfileClass) {

var params = {
    userId: userId,
    teamId: teamId,
    riskProfileClass: riskProfileClass
};

var data = JSON.stringify(params);
//if (!$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#riskProfileTable")) {

    var table = $("#riskProfileTable").DataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "WFMHome.aspx/GetRiskProfileDrillThroughDatatable",
        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            //aoData.push(JSON.stringify(params));
            $.ajax({
                "dataType": 'json',
                "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "type": "POST",
                "url": sSource,
                "data": data,
                "success": function (msg) {
                    var json = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);
                    fnCallback(json);
                    $("#riskProfileTable").show("fast", function () { $('#riskProfileTableLoading').hide("fast") });
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                    if (typeof console == "object") {
                        appendAlert("errorAlertPlaceholder", xhr.responseText, 1, "danger");
                        console.log(xhr.status + "," + xhr.responseText + "," + textStatus + "," + error);
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "CaseHandler" },
            { "data": "caseAreaText" },
            { "data": "RiskProfileText" },
            { "data": "PassChecks" },
            { "data": "F1Checks" },
            { "data": "F2Checks" },
            { "data": "F3Checks" },
            { "data": "CurrentChecks" }
        ]
    });
//} 
//else {
//        $('#riskProfileTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
//    }
};
```

Comment: Currently I have resolved my immediate problem by destroying, removing and appending the table definition within the function. I would like a more elegant solution though.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to replace the data you have now by the data coming from the server, try to replace the success method by:

```
"success": function (msg) {
    var json = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d); //I assume it's the data set
    var table = $("#riskProfileTable").DataTable();
    table.rows.clear(); //clear the current data
    table.rows.add(json).draw();
    $("#riskProfileTable").show("fast", function () { $('#riskProfileTableLoading').hide("fast") });
},
```